# WebSocket through proxy with Jboss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, jboss, proxy

I want to use websocket communication with my Jboss EAP 6.4 through proxy.

But in this version of jboss, the implementation of JSR-356 is org.apache.tomcat.websocket version 8.0.14 and doesn't support proxy configuration.

So i want to upgrade tomcat.websocket to use 8.0.36 version (tested on jboss eap 7.0, it works) in my jboss eap 6.

Unfortunately, in jboss eap 6, the tomcat.websocket package is include in jbossweb module (into the jar).

Do you think it's possible to exclude only the org.apache.tomcat.websocket package and include a new upgraded version ?

Thanks